# Meta-procyclic groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, pro-p-groups

> **Theorem.** *A pro-$p$ group is meta-procyclic iff it is a inverse limit of metacyclic $p$-groups.*

*Proof*. Let $G$ be a meta-procyclic pro-$p$ group with normal subgroup $N$ and let $M$ be an open normal subgroup. Then $G/M$ is procyclic since both the normal subgroup $NM/M$ and the quotient $(G/M)/(NM/M)$ are cylic $p$-groups... (continue) $\square$

- I cannot see why is $(G/M)/(NM/M)$ cyclic.

If necessary, I can write the complete proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G/M/(NM/M)$ is a quotient of $G/N$ (by $NM/N$) which is cyclic by assumption.